# How to show continuity of $f\colon \mathbb{c_0}\to \mathbb{c_0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{c}_{0}$ be a space of  sequences of real numbers convergent to $0$ with the following norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|$. Consider a function $f\colon \mathbb{c}_0\to \mathbb{c}_0$ defined by
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{y},$$
where $\mathbf{y}=(y_{n})\in \mathbb{c}_0$ and $y_n=\sqrt{|x_n|}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. How to prove that such a function is continuous in $\mathbb{c_0}$???

We should take a sequence $\mathbf{x}_n=(x_{n,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergent to some $\mathbf{\xi}$. Then, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}|x_{n,k}-\xi_{k}|=0.$$
We shall prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}|\sqrt{|x_{n,k}|}-\sqrt{|\xi_{k}|}\,\,|=0.$$
But how to obtain this?

Is $|\sqrt{|x_{n,k}|}-\sqrt{|\xi_k|}\,\,|\le \sqrt{||x_{n,k}|-|\xi_{k}||}\le \sqrt{|x_{n,k}-\xi_{k}}|$
enough? ($f(z)=\sqrt{|z|}$ is uniformly continuous?)

Comment: What is $\mathbb c_0$?

Comment: A space of sequences convergent to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument to avoid some of the hassle of working with sequences.  As you observed the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $\delta$ so that $|x-a| < \delta \implies |\sqrt x - \sqrt a| < \epsilon$ for all $x,a \in [0,\infty)$.

If ${\bf x} = (x_k)$ and ${\bf a} = (a_k)$ are sequences in $c_0$ with $\|{\bf x} - {\bf a}\|_\infty < \delta$ then for each index $k$ you have $$ |x_k - a_k| < \delta \implies ||x_k| - |a_k|| < \delta \implies |\sqrt{|x_k|} - \sqrt{|a_k|}| < \epsilon$$
which may be written as
$$|{\bf f(x)}_k - {\bf f(a)}_k| < \epsilon.$$  Take the supremum over $k$ to find
$$\|{\bf x} - {\bf a}\|_\infty < \delta \implies \|{\bf f(x)} - {\bf f(a)}\|_\infty \le \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. $\varepsilon - \delta$ argumentation is much better.